# Constructor Lists in particular order with pointers

Tags: c++, constructor

I am writing code that uses a library with no default constructor (there is, but it's soon to be deprecated, and throws warnings), and I'd like to use it inside a class. Now, I am aware that there are several answers for this in general, but none seem to answer my *particular* variant.

Here's why:
The library's constructor takes a pointer to two arrays that are used for input and output. I need to allocate memory for those arrays, and I have to do this *before* I call this library's constructor.

I thus need an alternative to constructor lists that will allow me to control the order, *or* I need to know how to allocate memory for objects inside a constructor list.

Here is the relevant code:

My class:

```
class audio_class{
arduinoFFT FFT;//cannot call constructor HERE, but that leaves the default!
double *real_samples;
double *imaginary;
//--snip--
};
```

Library's constructor:

```
arduinoFFT(double *vReal, double *vImag, uint16_t samples, double samplingFrequency);
```

My code's constructor:

```
audio_class::audio_class() {
  real_samples = new double[READINGS];
  imaginary = new double[READINGS];
  //Need to initialize arduinoFFT here? Or after allocation of samples, anyway. Constructor list would fire before I call the new[], and the pointers would be invalid. I think?
}

audio_class::~audio_class() {
  delete[] real_samples;
  delete[] imaginary;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of initialization of class data members is determined by the order of declaration in the class definition. (The order of member initializers in the constructor has no effect on this.) So you could rearrange the members to do something like:

```
class audio_class{
    double *real_samples;
    double *imaginary;
    arduinoFFT FFT;
    //--snip--
};

audio_class::audio_class() :
    real_samples(new double[READINGS]),
    imaginary(new double[READINGS]),
    FFT(real_samples, imaginary, READINGS, DFLT_FFT_FREQ)
{
}
```

But there's an unrelated issue here: this is not exception-safe. If either the second `new` or the `arduinoFFT` constructor throws an exception, the previous allocations are never deleted and are leaked. Plus dealing with `new` and `delete` yourself is trickier, and requires more code (obey at least the Rule of Three). So I'd recommend using `std::vector` here to switch to RAII / Rule of Zero, to fix all of that at once.

```
#include <vector>

class audio_class{
    std::vector<double> real_samples;
    std::vector<double> imaginary;
    arduinoFFT FFT;
    // No destructor declaration needed.
    //--snip--
};

audio_class::audio_class() :
    real_samples(READINGS),
    imaginary(READINGS),
    FFT(real_samples.data(), imaginary.data(), READINGS, DFLT_FFT_FREQ)
{
}
```

(This way still requires `FFT` to be declared after `real_samples` and `imaginary`, for the same reasons.)

Comment: I suppose I should ask if that works on Arduino (probably, but I've never used vectors). How does using the vectors change my code and how I access their content? Either way, that is exactly the information I was looking for, so thank you. I'll accept that shortly.